# Reduce the unicorn app server response time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, unicorn

I recently migrated to Unicorn from passenger to run my e-commerce application which is based on Ruby 2.0.0-p0 on Rails 3.2.13. The average response time of the app server thats unicorn is quite high according to newrelic metrics. How to tweak unicorn to reduce the app response time to less 500ms, presently I am experiencing more then 1200ms. I have attached the snap shot of the unicorn app server response time and also I have attached the unicorn.rb and nginx.conf
One thing we can notice that, Ruby itself is consuming more then 800ms. How can I reduce that? I am running AWS ubuntu ec2 instance. I am running on large instances.

```
require 'unicorn/oob_gc'

# this should probably be between CPU threads and CPU threads * 2
worker_processes 2

# this is your current deployed code symlink
root = "/path/to/app"
working_directory root


# don't use TCP to talk to Nginx
listen "/tmp/unicorn.sock"

# how long is it ok for your workers to hang
timeout 30

pid "#{root}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"

stderr_path "#{root}/log/unicorn_stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{root}/log/unicorn_stdout.log"

preload_app true
GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=) and
  GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true

check_client_connection false

before_exec do |server|
  ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = "#{root}/Gemfile"
end

before_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!

  old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
  if old_pid != server.pid
    begin
      sig = (worker.nr + 1) >= server.worker_processes ? :QUIT : :TTOU
      Process.kill(sig, File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to sent QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

here is my nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 2;

user ubuntu ubuntu; # for systems with "nobody" as a group instead

# Feel free to change all paths to suite your needs here, of course
pid /etc/nginx/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.error.log;

events {
  worker_connections 1024; # increase if you have lots of clients
  accept_mutex off; # "on" if nginx worker_processes > 1
  # use epoll; # enable for Linux 2.6+
  # use kqueue; # enable for FreeBSD, OSX
}

http {
  # nginx will find this file in the config directory set at nginx build time
  include mime.types;

  # fallback in case we can't determine a type
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  # click tracking!
  # access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.access.log combined;

  # you generally want to serve static files with nginx since neither
  # Unicorn nor Rainbows! is optimized for it at the moment
  sendfile on;

  tcp_nopush on; # off may be better for *some* Comet/long-poll stuff
  tcp_nodelay off; # on may be better for some Comet/long-poll stuff
  client_max_body_size 2M;
  client_body_buffer_size 64k;
  #file_cache
  open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=20s; 
  open_file_cache_valid    30s; 
  open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
  open_file_cache_errors   off; 



  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_min_length 500;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
#  gzip_types text/plain text/html text/xml text/css
#             text/comma-separated-values
#             text/javascript application/x-javascript
#             application/atom+xml;

  # this can be any application server, not just Unicorn/Rainbows!
  upstream app_server {


    # for UNIX domain socket setups:
    #server unix:/path/to/.unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
 ;
    # for TCP setups, point these to your backend servers

    # server 192.168.0.9:8080 fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # path for static files
    root path/to/app;


    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_redirect off;

       proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

    # Rails error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
      root path/to/app;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the attachment of the newrelic

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is not related to unicorn or nginx, but rather the code of your Rails application.

You are doing something slow in your application that you're going to need to fix.

Using newrelic in development mode for detailed traces may help you find your performance problems.